# How to transform sub-list into array index?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a 2D array (`array`) of length `10x10`

```
array = ImageData[RandomImage[10, 10]];
```

and I have a list of indices for the desired array elements.

```
desired = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, 
  {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 
  2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 
  5}, {6, 6}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}, {8, 3}, {8, 4}, {8, 
  5}, {8, 6}};
```

One way to access the desired elements is `array[[desired[[i,1]],desired[[i,2]]]]`.

But I think there must be some better approaches to do this. Therefore, my question is: how smartly can this be done?

Comment: `desired[[i]]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Extract

```
Extract[Array[x, {10, 10}], desired]
```

> {x[1, 3], x[1, 4], x[1, 5], x[1, 6], x[2, 3], x[2, 4], x[2, 5], 
>        x[2, 6], x[3, 3], x[3, 4], x[3, 5], x[3, 6], x[4, 3], x[4, 4], 
>        x[4, 5], x[4, 6], x[5, 2], x[5, 3], x[5, 4], x[5, 5], x[5, 6], 
>        x[6, 2], x[6, 3], x[6, 4], x[6, 5], x[6, 6], x[7, 3], x[7, 4], 
>        x[7, 5], x[7, 6], x[8, 3], x[8, 4], x[8, 5], x[8, 6]}

```
Extract[array, desired]
```

> {7.26511, 0.161259, 3.68567, 3.39165, 7.61135, 4.81733, 3.86941, 
>       9.2501, 0.627509, 6.31271, 9.98706, 4.64997, 5.17223, 4.92969, 5.886, 
>       5.401, 5.62913, 3.50379, 6.28734, 6.12715, 7.69792, 7.2367, 3.36751, 
>       8.13952, 2.09141, 1.7609, 9.10072, 1.05672, 1.78437, 3.22518,
>       1.44075, 3.28318, 7.89254, 6.47532}

### Part + Apply

```
array[[##]] & @@@ desired  == %
```

> True

### Table

```
Table[array[[## & @@ i]], {i, desired}] == %
```

> True

Comment: `Extract[array,desired]` looks to be the simplest and most compact one.

Comment: and fastest as well.